# Calculate time difference from non-consective rows using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, time

I have a table :

```
ID  INDEXNO PO_NO   ITEM_CD     PROC_NO SEQ STATUS  TIME_OCCUR      MC_NO   OPT_TIME    SUB_ID
72  130671  GV13719 3C0031092   617098  10  Start   23-03-18 10:04  ADC001  NULL        NULL
74  130671  GV13719 3C0031092   617098  7   Finish  23-03-18 10:47  CDC001  NULL        70
70  130671  GV13719 3C0031092   617098  7   Start   21-03-18 8:53   CDC001  NULL        74
```

I want to calculate the time difference of 02 non-consective rows, if SUB_ID is not null . I google a lot but none of the solution that I found satisfies my expected result that look like:

```
ID  INDEXNO PO_NO   ITEM_CD     PROC_NO SEQ STATUS  TIME_OCCUR      MC_NO   OPT_TIME    SUB_ID
72  130671  GV13719 3C0031092   617098  10  Start   23-03-18 10:04  ADC001  NULL        NULL
74  130671  GV13719 3C0031092   617098  7   Finish  23-03-18 10:47  CDC001  2994        70
70  130671  GV13719 3C0031092   617098  7   Start   21-03-18 8:53   CDC001  NULL        74
```

by using this query:

```
;WITH rows AS
(
    SELECT  
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TIME_OCCUR) AS rn
    FROM    
        [PROC_MN].[dbo].[TBL_CURRENT_STATUS]
    WHERE 
        SUB_ID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT  
    DATEDIFF(minute, mc.[TIME_OCCUR], mp.[TIME_OCCUR])
FROM    
    rows mc
JOIN
    rows mp ON mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
```

Comment: That's 2 days of difference. It's only looking at rows with sub_id btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RIGHT JOIN` with your output

```
;WITH rows AS
(
    SELECT  
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TIME_OCCUR) AS rn
    FROM    
        [TBL_CURRENT_STATUS]
    WHERE 
        SUB_ID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT  
    op.[ID], 
    op.[INDEXNO], 
    op.[PO_NO], 
    op.[ITEM_CD], 
    op.[PROC_NO], 
    op.[SEQ], 
    op.[STATUS], 
    op.[TIME_OCCUR], 
    op.[MC_NO],
    DATEDIFF(minute, mc.[TIME_OCCUR], mp.[TIME_OCCUR]) as OPT_TIME, 
    op.[SUB_ID]   
FROM    
    rows mc
JOIN
    rows mp ON mc.rn = mp.rn - 1 
RIGHT JOIN
   TBL_CURRENT_STATUS op
ON op.id=mp.id
```

Demo Link

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ca1b1/10

Output

```
ID  INDEXNO PO_NO   ITEM_CD     PROC_NO SEQ STATUS  TIME_OCCUR              MC_NO   OPT_TIME  SUB_ID
72  130671  GV13719 3C0031092   617098  10  Start   2018-03-23T10:04:00Z    ADC001  (null)    (null)
74  130671  GV13719 3C0031092   617098  7   Finish  2018-03-23T10:47:00Z    CDC001  2994      70
70  130671  GV13719 3C0031092   617098  7   Start   2018-03-21T08:53:00Z    CDC001  (null)    74
```

Update Table Using Cte You need to use Temp Table LIke This

```
WITH rows AS
(
    SELECT  
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TIME_OCCUR) AS rn
    FROM    
        [TBL_CURRENT_STATUS]
    WHERE 
        SUB_ID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT  
    mp.[ID], 
    DATEDIFF(minute, mc.[TIME_OCCUR], mp.[TIME_OCCUR]) AS OPT_TIME
    INTO #test
FROM    
    rows mc
JOIN
    rows mp ON mc.rn = mp.rn - 1;

UPDATE TBL_CURRENT_STATUS
SET OPT_TIME=t.OPT_TIME
FROM TBL_CURRENT_STATUS 
INNER JOIN #test t
ON
t.ID=TBL_CURRENT_STATUS.ID;
```

Comment: How to update the OPT_TIME only by using the above WITH clause?